# Grouping elements by the first attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I display an alert with the elements second attribute grouped by the first atribute, example:

```
<a href="#b" attA=1 attB=18 >Here</a>
<a href="#b" attA=1 attB=27>Here</a>
<a href="#b" attA=1 attB=31>Here</a>
<a href="#b" attA=2 attB=84>Here</a>
```

when you click on any of the attA links it would display:

```
alert("atta=1 and attB=18,27,31");
```

and click on the attB:

```
alert("atta=2 and attB=84");
```

hard, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var attA = $(this).attr('attA'),
        attB = $.map($('a'), function(link){
            if($(link).attr('attA') == attA) {
                return $(link).attr('attB');
            }
        });

    alert('atta=' + attA + ' and attB=' + attB.join(','));
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eLBp4/)

Comment: would you have to know if the link would not be "this"? like a other link(< a > without attributes only a class=aclass) calling this Alert

Answer (score 2):

`attA` is not a valid attribute, you can use `data-*` attributes instead also note that you should wrap the values with quotation marks.

```
<a href="#b" data-atta='1' data-attb='18'>Here</a>
<a href="#b" data-atta='1' data-attb='27'>Here</a>
<a href="#b" data-atta='1' data-attb='31'>Here</a>
<a href="#b" data-atta='2' data-attb='84'>Here</a>
```

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var a = this.dataset.atta;
    var b = $('a[data-atta='+a+']').map(function() {
        return this.dataset.attb
    }).get().join();
    alert('atta: ' + a + ", attb=" + b)
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XrF4p/

Answer (score 1):

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pRENf/)

```
$(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $attA = $(this).attr('attA');
        var $attB = $('a[attA="'+ $attA +'"]');
        var arr = [];
        $.each($attB, function(){

             arr.push( $(this).attr('attB'));
        });
        alert('attA - ' + $attA + ' :: attB - '+ arr.join());        
    });
});​
```